# Springboot Get Api Endpoint returns 404 not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest

I'm trying to create a Springboot Get API endpoint but I get a 404 not found error' here is my code

profile.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Profile {

    private String slackUsername;
    private Boolean backend;
    private Integer age;
    private  String bio;
```

ProfileController

```
@RestController
public class ProfileController {

    @Autowired
    private Profile profile;

    @GetMapping(path = "/profile")
    private ResponseEntity<String> userInfo(){

        profile.setSlackUsername("Ajava");
        profile.setBackend(true);
        profile.setAge(00);
        profile.setBio("My name is Anakhe Ajayi, I'm learning Java everyday and I love Jesus");
        return ResponseEntity.ok(profile.toString());
    }
```

Main

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com/ajavacode/HNGBackendStage1/api.profile")
public class HngBackendStage1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HngBackendStage1Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

[image: Project folder structur]

porm.xml
[image]

Comment: Can you please share your project folder structure?

Comment: I have added the folder structure

Comment: What are you trying with `@ComponentScan("com/ajavacode/HNGBackendStage1/api.profile")`?

Comment: @PlusUltra - Thanks for sharing folder structure, ComponentScan annotation value is incorrect. please fix it as per my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please fix the value in `@ComponentScan` annotation like this and try again.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.ajavacode.HNGBackendStage1")
public class HngBackendStage1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HngBackendStage1Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Also there is an issue in `ProfileController` class, you are auto wiring `Profile` class inside it. Profile class is not a bean so this is incorrect and userInfo() method is private, it should be public. Here is the fixed version.

```
@RestController
public class ProfileController {


    @GetMapping(path = "/profile")
    public ResponseEntity<String> userInfo(){
        Profile profile=new Profile();
        profile.setSlackUsername("Ajava");
        profile.setBackend(true);
        profile.setAge(00);
        profile.setBio("My name is Anakhe Ajayi, I'm learning Java everyday and I love Jesus");
        return ResponseEntity.ok(profile.toString());
    }
```

Comment: JVM won't start, it suggests I map to the appropriate class

Comment: you main class is present inside com.ajavacode.HNGBackendStage1 package right?

Comment: Field profile in com.ajavacode.HNGBackendStage1.api.ProfileController required a bean of type 'com.ajavacode.HNGBackendStage1.api.Profile' that could not be found.

thanks for your response

Comment: Yes that's where my Main class is

Comment: you are auto wiring DTO inside controller that is incorrect.

Comment: @Autowired
    private Profile profile;

Comment: because Profile class is not a bean.

Comment: You should create a Profile class object inside userInfo() method.                  
 Profile profile=new Profile();

Comment: That didn't work as well

Comment: What is error now? BTW I have updated my answer with ProfileController class fix.

Comment: Same 404 not found error

Comment: I can see userInfo() method is private. Can you please make it public and try again

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. when I removed the Autowired  and mapped Componentscan as you suggested, The bug was fixed

Comment: Good to know that issue is finally resolved  :)

Comment: One more thing please,  this returns the reference part but I'm trying to get a String representation of the Variables

Comment: You can return profile instead of profile.toString()

Comment: Method return type should be Profile or ResponseEntity<Profile>

Comment: Yes, I did that but it displayed as a list, for the task it is to display as a String

Comment: Ok Can you share your expected output?

Comment: something like this - {"slackUsername":"Benrobo","backend":true,"age":20,"bio":"I\"m a chef ‍, who cooks but not in a kitchen. I solve problem for a living using 1's and 0's ‍.\n      Fullstack Software Engineer"}

Answer (score 0):

You have to check some items in your code;

1. Make sure the endpoint you are sending request , is correct .
2. Add @RequestMapping("Profile") to the controller to avoid repeated endpoint and reduce the ambiguity
3. Make sure your pom is correct

Comment: Thanks, but that did not work, I have added the porm file, please have a look

Comment: What url are you sending request?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, there are a few things to mention.

First of all, your package structure looks good (besides the fact that I, personally, would keep everything lowercase).

With the package structure that you have in place, you actually don't need any `@ComponentScan` annotation at all. The annotation `@SpringBootApplication` at your main class by default scans for components with the package of that class as the base package. So you only need to set something if you want to explicitly scan for components in some other package, e.g., either at a higher level or if you want to skip packages in the hierarchy.

Next thing is the controller. Question here is: What do you actually want to achieve?

I assume that you want to build an application that provides a `GET /profile` endpoint that returns a response object like the example below:

```json
{

  "slackUsername": "alice",
  "backend": false,
  "age": 42,
  "bio": "I'm just an example"
}
```

If my understanding is correct, there is at least one thing that is a bit odd: Currently, you defined a controller that would return the String representation of the `Profile` object. That isn't necessarily something as shown in the example above. If you do not override the `toString()` method, the result would be something like `com.ajavacode.HNGBackendStage1.api.Profile@6d06d69c` (see [this Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-tostring) for instance). And even if you use Lombok's `@Data` or `@ToString` annotations, the result will not be a JSON or XML representation but something that is suitable for logging, for instance.

Spring will already take care of the serialization into JSON (or XML) format. In your controller you can just return the `Profile` object or, alternatively, a `ResponseEntity<Profile>`:

```java
@GetMapping(path = "/profile")
public Profile userInfo(){
  Profile profile=new Profile();
  profile.setSlackUsername("Ajava");
  profile.setBackend(true);
  profile.setAge(00);
  profile.setBio("My name is Anakhe Ajayi, I'm learning Java everyday and I love Jesus");
  return profile;
}
```

The above example would create a response with the profile as the response body and HTTP status code 200 OK. In case you use `ResponseEntity`, you could also adjust the HTTP status code but in your case that probably is not necessary (yet).

Autowiring the `Profile` class also is not correct, as already mentioned. You only need to autowire classes beans, i.e., classes that are annotated with `@Component`, `@Service`, or `@Repository`. The class you "autowired" is just a POJO class representing some "data object", nothing that provides any kind of business logic.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. I have refactored the package name